# How to add memory usage to Snakemake reports

Tags: python, snakemake

It seems that by default, Snakemake includes runtime in its reports. Is there any way to also add memory usage to the report as well?

Also, is there any way for us to see maximum memory usage of Snakemake over the course of a pipeline? I know you can use the `benchmark` directive to look at memory usage of an individual process, but this doesn't take into account how Snakemake runs things in parallel. This means that the total memory usage of Snakemake cannot be represented so easily using just `benchmark`.